# I want 5 min after the page is loaded. Activate a button that is disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use PrimeFaces 7.0

I tried to make a function with jquery but it doesn't work.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if (document.getElementById("resultsFormId:neueTanAnfordern") != null) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('resultsFormId:neueTanAnfordern').disabled = false;
        document.getElementById('resultsFormId:neueTanAnfordern').removeAttribute("aria-disabled");
        document.getElementById('resultsFormId:neueTanAnfordern').removeAttribute("disabled");
      }, 15000);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ui-g-6 ui-md-3 ui-lg-3">
  <button id="resultsFormId:neueTanAnfordern" name="resultsFormId:neueTanAnfordern" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left ui-state-disabled" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;resultsFormId:neueTanAnfordern&quot;,f:&quot;resultsFormId&quot;,u:&quot;resultsFormId&quot;});return false;"
    type="submit" disabled="disabled" role="button" aria-disabled="true">
<span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c ui-icon-phone-android"></span><span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Neue TAN anfordern</span></button>

</div>
```

before function execution :

```
<div class="ui-g-6 ui-md-3 ui-lg-3">
<button id="resultsFormId:neueTanAnfordern" name="resultsFormId:neueTanAnfordern" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left ui-state-disabled"
onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;resultsFormId:neueTanAnfordern&quot;,f:&quot;resultsFormId&quot;,u:&quot;resultsFormId&quot;});return false;" type="submit" disabled="disabled" role="button" aria-disabled="true">
<span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c ui-icon-phone-android"></span><span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Neue TAN anfordern</span></button>

</div>
```

After function execution :

```
<div class="ui-g-6 ui-md-3 ui-lg-3">
<button id="resultsFormId:neueTanAnfordern" name="resultsFormId:neueTanAnfordern" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left ui-state-disabled"
onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;resultsFormId:neueTanAnfordern&quot;,f:&quot;resultsFormId&quot;,u:&quot;resultsFormId&quot;});return false;" type="submit" role="button">
<span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c ui-icon-phone-android"></span><span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Neue TAN anfordern</span>
</button>
</div>
```

aria-disabled="true" is not im Button tag , but Button stay disabled

I thank you in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove one ready
2. Use jQuery selector - you need to escape the colon
3. Cache the element
4. Use on click and either make the button type="button" or preventDefault
5. No need to set disable to false if you remove it

```js
$(function() {
  const $neueTanAnfordern = $("#resultsFormId\\:neueTanAnfordern");
  console.log($neueTanAnfordern.length)
  if ($neueTanAnfordern.length > 0) {
    $neueTanAnfordern.on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const parts = this.id.split(":");
      PrimeFaces.ab({
        s: this.id,
        f: parts[0],
        u: parts[0]
      });
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
      $neueTanAnfordern
        .removeAttr("disabled")
        .removeAttr("aria-disabled");
    }, 3000); // changed to make it faster to test
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ui-g-6 ui-md-3 ui-lg-3">
  <button id="resultsFormId:neueTanAnfordern" name="resultsFormId:neueTanAnfordern" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left ui-state-disabled" type="submit" disabled="disabled" role="button" aria-disabled="true">
<span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c ui-icon-phone-android"></span><span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Neue TAN anfordern</span></button>

</div>
```

Comment: it would be even better to just use PF widget API and call .disable() on the button